# Integrate a rule

Tags: replacement, rule

I want to implement a simple function to solve an exact differential equation, it's:

```
exact[Mx_, Ny_] := c + Integrate[g'[y], y] /. (Solve[
    D[Integrate[Mx, x] + g[y], y] == Ny, g'[y]])
```

Solve gives a rule: `{{g'[y]-> something something}}` and I want to Integrate the *something something*, but it just integrates `g'[y]` and gives as a result `g[y]`.

Is there a way to force *Mathematica* to first apply the rule and then integrate?

Comment: Try `Integrate[g'[y] /. First@Solve[...], y]`

Comment: Just tried it, still get the same.

Comment: I used a doble replacement rule, not very elegant, but it worked: `Integrate[a[y], y] + c /. (a[y] -> g'[y]
   /. Solve[D[Integrate[Mx, x] + g[y], y] == Ny, g'[y]][[1]])`. Still I'm hoping a better solution will arrive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a long-form of the suggestion I showed in comments, where I am afraid I was not clear. I meant to suggest that you should do two things: 1. do the replacement *within* `Integrate`; 2. apply First to the result of `Solve` so you get an expression, rather than a single-element list containing your expression, from the replacement:

```
Clear[exact]
exact[Mx_, Ny_] := 
   c + Integrate[g'[y] /. First@Solve[D[Integrate[Mx, x] + g[y], y] == Ny, g'[y]], y]
```

Let's try it out on something simple:

```
exact[2 x + 2 y, 2 x + 2 y]

(* Out: c + y^2 *)
```

This seems to be what you wanted. Reconstructing piece by piece:

- `Integrate[Mx, x]` becomes `Integrate[2 x + 2 y, x]`, which returns `2 (x^2/2 + x y)`;
- Add `g[y]` to get `2 (x^2/2 + x y) + g[y]`;
- Take the derivative wrt $y$ and set it equal to `Ny`: `2 x + g'[y] == 2 x + 2 y`
- Solving for `g'[y]` returns `{{g'[y] -> 2 y}}`; take the first part, to give `{g'[y] -> 2 y}`
- Summarizing, you then apply the replacement within `Integrate`:

  ```
  g'[y] /. First@Solve[D[Integrate[2 x + 2 y, x] + g[y], y] == 2 x + 2 y, g'[y]]
  (* Out: 2 y *)
  ```
- Finally, find the antiderivative wrt $y$, which is `y^2`, and add `c`. This confirms the result obtained with your `exact` function.

Comment: Thank you very much, when I tried it the first time, I was still using the replacement rule _after_ the **Integrate**. This worked just perfect.

Comment: @Theennus Glad it helped!